# How to assign content to publishing page programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, libraries

What `SPListTemplateType` corresponds to standard `Pages` list? I know that `Site Pages` type is 119. But cannot find a type for `Pages`. I verified that they do not belong to type 119. Thank you.

Comment: sorry its a bit unclear, do you mean, you want  to add content type to the pages library or individual page in the page library? The list template type for publishing page library is 850.

Comment: @Gautam Sheth, Thank you very much for comment. I was looking for a type for the whole library. Your magic number 850 worked just fine. You should post it as an answer for everybody's awareness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list template type for a Publishing Page library is `850`.

To know the list template type, I used the `_spPageContextInfo.listBaseTemplate` value on a publishing page . Not sure if its available in OnPremise, but works in SP Online.